# There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace

Tags: migration, magento2.3.1

Migration issue from M1.9 to M2.3.1

After importing settings successfully when I run data migration command it gave me following error:

```
There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.
```

Comment: you have data-migration tool with composer tool successfully?

Comment: Yes! also fix above issue, let me post my findings on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually After migrate settings, I had imported one wrong custom module's  setting into M2 core_config_data table. Due to which non of the cli commands workable:
i run just `php bin/magento`
I had following error at the end.

```
Notice: Undefined index: jobs in /usr/local/ampps/www/mage231/vendor/magento/module-cron/Model/Config/Converter/Db.php on line 39
```

So I fix this issue (In your case issue can be different but direction is same) and after that run migration command.

Answer (score 0):

There must have some problems during the process. You need to re-install the migration tool following this dev document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html.

And run it again!